# Firebase intergration not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have added the Firebase frameworks (without cocoa pods) using the instructions. I have also added the 5 dependencies and added the -ObjC linker.

However when adding the init line

```
Firebase *myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://appname.firebaseio.com"]
```

I get the error saying "Firebase is not a dylib" (dynamic library) .. And so the code won't compile.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Firebase` is the old class name - you'll probably want `FIRDatabase`. Take a look at the [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites) and the [iOS migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) for the changes from the 2.x SDK to the 3.x one.

If you're still seeing linker errors:

Make sure that the frameworks are under the *Link Binary With Libraries* section of the *Build Phases* tab in your target settings.

If you have a "Frameworks" group in your app, Xcode should do this if you just drag it them in there.

Comment: Thank you, I literally just found this.